# React useContext - wait for api to finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const tableContext = React.createContext();
const tableContextProvider = ({children}) => {
   const [isTableOne, setTableOne] = useState(false);
   const [isTableTwo, setTableTwo] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
       setTableValues();
   }, []);

   function setTableValue() {
       // api call returns result
       setTableOne(result.IS_TABLE_ONE); // true
       setTableTwo(result.IS_TABLE_TWO); // false
   }

   return (<TableContext.Provider value={{isTableOne, isTableTwo}}>{children}</TableContext.Provider>);
};
```

In a different component, the result shows:

```
{isTableOne:false, isTableTwo:false}
{isTableOne:true, isTableTwo:false}
```

It returns two objects and it takes some time to return the second one. How could I make it wait and only return the last result?

Comment: The default state as context will be passed to the subscribed component (one that's using useContext) . Now for the default value , it's up to you how you want to render based on it. As soon as latest value comes after the API call, the global context gets updated and the subscribed component received the new object. So it's natural to see default object first and object which got passed after the api call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your request is being made inside that useEffect, here's how you can do it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async init(){
      const response = await myApiCall(); // Wait for response with a promise
      setTableValues(); // Only call the setter after you get the values
    }
    init();

},[]);
```